# why the red part doesn't take only 100% of the available height

Tags: html, css, height

why the red part doesn't take only 100% of the height available
i mean why the red part take 100% of 100vh
and not 100vh - 10px - 40px (black and blue heights)

```css
.black {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}

.red {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
      <div class="black"></div>
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

100% is not calculating **remaining available** part for you. You can use `calc()` function of css for it.

```
.red {
  height: calc(100% - 10px - 40px);
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Percentages in CSS are [relative to another value](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#percentages). In this case, your percentage is relative to the parent's `height` property.

Since the red element is 100% of the parent's `height`, and the parent's height is `100vh`, the red element will also have a height of `100vh`.

To redistribute remaining space automatically, you can use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) or [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout):

```css
/* Flexbox */
#flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#flexbox .red {flex-grow: 1}

/* CSS Grid */
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

/* Presentational styling */
#flexbox, #grid {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}

.black {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}
.red {background-color: red}
.blue {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>Flexbox</header>
  <div id="flexbox">
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <header>CSS Grid</header>
  <div id="grid">
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Alternatively, you can calculate the remaining space yourself with [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), either with [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) or by using [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties):

```css
/* calc() */
#calc {
  --h-black: 10px;
  --h-blue: 40px;
}
#calc .red {
  height: calc(100% - var(--h-black) - var(--h-blue));
}

/* Presentational styling */
#calc {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}

.black {
  height: var(--h-black);
  background-color: black;
}
.red {background-color: red}
.blue {
  height: var(--h-blue);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="calc">
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```